# 「虚有其表」这个成语可以用來形容好看，但内容全错的报告吗？

Tags: usage, idioms, chengyu

I have a question:

成语－虚有其表－可以用在下面情形吗？

---

有一个人的报告写的很好看，很漂亮，可内容都错了。

---

有没有其他的成语？ Any suggestion?

Comment: “徒有其表” is generally for a person, and for what you refer, a report, you can use “华而不实”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**有其表** 可以描述 **寫得很好看，很漂亮** 。

**虛** 和 **內容都錯** 有一點點差距，但是基本上還是可以用。因為 **內容都錯** 要用 **錯** 來形容，但是 **錯有其表** 並不是常用的成語。所以，退而求其次，用 **虛** 也無不可。 **空有其表** 倒還聽過。

其他類似的詞還有下面這些，但不一定是成語，也有些許差距，提供參考。

空大老脬（ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄉㄚˋ　ㄌㄠˇ　ㄆㄠ／kōng dà lǎo pāo）：表面雖強大，而實則虛浮萎弱。

空心湯糰（ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄒㄧㄣ　ㄊㄤ　ㄊㄨㄢˊ／kōng xīn tāng tuán）
空心湯圓（ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄒㄧㄣ　ㄊㄤ　ㄩㄢˊ／kōng xīn tāng yuán）
空心蘿蔔（ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄒㄧㄣ　ㄌㄨㄛˊ　ㄅㄛ˙／kōng xīn luó bo）
空心架子（ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄒㄧㄣ　ㄐㄧㄚˋ　ㄗ˙／kōng xīn jià zi）
這四詞都比喻徒有虛名，而無實在利益。

一紙空文（ㄧ　ㄓˇ　ㄎㄨㄥ　ㄨㄣˊ／yī zhǐ kōng wén）：徒具文字而無實際效用的文書。

以上來自 http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/

另外，和 **很好看，很漂亮，可內容都錯** 有點相關的詞還有：徒具形式、徒具外表、華而不實、花瓶。

@Tang Ho 的 **金玉其外，敗絮其中** 倒很貼切。

Comment: The structure of 虛有其表 is "虛有"(unsubstantially having) + "其表" (ones appearance). ] it is not "虛" + "有其表".

Comment: 下雨天留客天天留我不留。标点各人不同。 '义不容辞'就分在'义'后。虽然，'虚有其表'大多用来形容人，但用来比喻事物，也应该是可以的。 _他写的报告真是虚有其表。_

Answer (score 1):

虛有(unsubstantially having) + 其表 (ones appearance)

虛有其表 means "all appearance but no substance" or " contradictory to the impressive exterior"

You can use it to describe someone:

- seem strong but can't actually fight
- seem smart but dumb as a brick

You can use it to describe something:

- seem impressive but is actually useless

> 有一个人的报告写的很好看，很漂亮，可内容都错了。

It only illustrates the person is 无能 (incompetent). Unless you also stated "he seems very smart", you cannot use 虛有其表 to describe him.

To use this term to describe the reports he wrote is not appropriate because "good penmanship" doesn't necessary contradict "wrong information" - the reports can be good looking and wrong.

> 有没有其他的成语？ Any suggestion?

有名无实 (in name only)

浪得虛名 (undeservingly enjoy a good reputation )

外強中乾 (look vigorous outside but exhausted inside)

金玉其外，败絮其中 ( look great outside but rotten inside)

Answer (score 0):

虚有其表. English equivalent "things that looks better than it was",  with additional description.
To critique the article written in flowery language but contain tons of mistake  : 
某人写的报告用词华丽辞藻，其实内容空泛，虚有其表。

If you want to say somebody fancy article contains too many mistake,  you can use the proverb 错误百出 as contrast to the flowery language. 
某人写的报告用词华丽辞藻，其实内容错误百出得令人不忍卒睹.

某人写的报告用词华丽辞藻，其实内容错误百出, 全是瞎扯(/鬼扯）.

By the way, mandarin usual don't say "有一个人", but "某人“ , "某某" .